# Why 'without' method returns different results depending on context?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to filter a `Backbone collection` using `_.without` method.

It returns correct results (only completed Todos) in this form of invocation:

```
return this.without.apply(this, this.active());
```

but not in this one:

```
return _.without(this.models, this.active());
```

In latter statement it returns array containing **ALL** models from collection.

Can't I use `Underscore` methods directly but only through Backbone's `this` context?

How to make 2nd statement work?

**todos.js**

```
var app = app || {};

var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: app.Todo,
  active: function() {
    return this.filter(function(todo) {
      return todo.get('completed') === false;
    });
  },
  completed: function() {
    return this.without.apply(this, this.active());
    // return _.without(this.models, this.active()); <--- Problem is here
  }
});

app.Todos = new Todos();
```

**ADDED LATER:**

Since _`.without` method does not accept array as a second parameter `_.difference` is more suitable for my task.

```
return _.difference(this.models, this.active());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use Undersore's [`without`](http://underscorejs.org/#without) method improperly. It expects **scalar** value for 2nd parameter, whereas you pass `array`.

Actually you don't need `_.without` at all.

Don't try to reuse your `active` method in `completed` method. This is a **bad** practice. `completed` method has to be implemented by the same approach as `active`.

So the code should look like this:

```
var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: app.Todo,
  active: function() {
    return this.filter(function(todo) {
      return todo.get('completed') === false;
    });
  },
  completed: function() {
    return this.filter(function(todo) {
      return todo.get('completed') === true;
    });
  }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

**Q:** So why the first invocation (which uses `apply`) works?

**A:** Because [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method converts `this.active()` result, which is `array`, to list of values, which is exactly expected by `_.without` method. So this invocation works unlike the second one which is not equivalent to the first.

However, as mentioned above, such type of code reusing is strongly **unrecommended** since it obscures the code logic, apart from the double array processing overhead.

Comment: But how does _.without work in first form of invocation if it expects a scalar value? this.without.apply(this, this.active())

Comment: >This is a bad practice    Why so? It's a code reuse. DRY principle.

Comment: >Not for your case Can you explain? As for me it's a perfect case of DRY.

Comment: Have you seen the sources of [Todos Example](http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html)?
Look at implementation of [`completed`](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone/js/collections/todos.js#L20) and [remaining`](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone/js/collections/todos.js#L25) methods. They are like yours `active` and `completed` methods. But do you see any reusing like yours in their implementation?  No, you can't see so, because such _reusing_ is unnecessary yet undesired.

Comment: @hindmost , can you answer the asked question . i.e why the second invocation is not working? i could'nt get it

Comment: @aktiv-coder I already gave answer to the question: _Because that code is wrong (use improper syntax)_

Comment: @hindmost thanks for replying, The backbone library passes them as arguments with out making any changes even in first method of invocation. then in this case even the first method shouldn't as per your explanation.